glmmTMB nbinom1 computing incorrect? coef
I have the fixed effect model (no random effects) glucose ~ genotype, where genotype is a factor with two levels. A quasipoisson and negative binomial GLM should estimate the same coefficients. But, glmmTMB(nbinom1) does not compute model coefficients that match glm(quasipoisson), glmTMBB(nbinom2), or glm.nb. Because the coefficients differ, the estimated marginal means of the groups differ. These should be the same among functions and equivalent to the sample means, yes? What's going on?
library(data.table)
library(MASS)
library(glmmTMB)
fd <- data.table(
  genotype = rep(c("WT", "KO"), each = 8),
  tumors = rnegbin(8*2, mu = rep(c(5, 10), each = 8), theta = 1)
)
qp1 <- glm(tumors ~ genotype,
           family = quasipoisson(link = "log"),
           data = fd)
qp2 <- glmmTMB(tumors ~ genotype,
               family = nbinom1(link = "log"),
               data = fd)
nb1 <- glm.nb(tumors ~ genotype,
           data = fd)
nb2 <- glmmTMB(tumors ~ genotype,
               family = nbinom2(link = "log"),
               data = fd)
coef(summary(qp1))
coef(summary(qp2))$cond
coef(summary(nb1))
coef(summary(nb2))$cond

             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  2.431418  0.2891563  8.408662 7.631869e-07
genotypeWT  -1.215023  0.6044945 -2.009981 6.410986e-02
              Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  2.3225197  0.3044603  7.628318 2.378361e-14
genotypeWT  -0.8076885  0.4786590 -1.687399 9.152671e-02
             Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  2.431418  0.3515361  6.916553 4.627644e-12
genotypeWT  -1.215023  0.5226885 -2.324564 2.009530e-02
             Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  2.431419  0.3515362  6.916554 4.627620e-12
genotypeWT  -1.215022  0.5226886 -2.324563 2.009535e-02

Update
In the comments, PBulls states that my expectation occurs only in special cases and linked to a post. The special case is when the predictor is a categorical (factor) variable, which is of course my case and why I have posted this question. The link is useful because in a response, user cardinal gives the math for why the coefficients of all GLMs will output the same coefficients (or the equivalent if some other link) if the predictor is a factor. So, again, why isn't the case with glmmTMB(family = nbinom1)?
I've modified the code from user cardinal's response in that link to include both quasipoisson fits. These are the coefficients in models with no intercept (so these should equal the sample means).
      negbin  poisson gaussian invgauss    gamma qpoisson qpoissson_tmb
XX1 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107      4.288181
XX2 4.790820 4.790820 4.790820 4.790820 4.790820 4.790820      4.789353
XX3 4.841033 4.841033 4.841033 4.841033 4.841033 4.841033      4.811718

Here are the coefficients from models with the intercept. Here, the coefficients for X2 and X3 (which are the effects that we are trying to estimate) differ by about 10% from the other glms.
              negbin  poisson gaussian invgauss    gamma qpoisson qpoissson_tmb
(Intercept) 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107 4.234107     4.2881807
XX2         0.556713 0.556713 0.556713 0.556713 0.556713 0.556713     0.5011718
XX3         0.606926 0.606926 0.606926 0.606926 0.606926 0.606926     0.5235374


Why would you expect a linear and a quadratic variance function to match? The quadratic form (nb2) is definitely the more common one and is usually the one being fit if it's not otherwise specified (e.g. glm.nb), but you could even make the exponent another parameter if you so wish.

PBulls - my response is just a restatement of my question. If I specify log link with all four functions, I expect the same coefficients. These coefficients add up to equal the (log) treatment means. And the estimates are all the same (see table above) EXCEPT the glmmTMB(nbinom1) estimates. That's my question, is there something wrong with glmmTMB estimates OR am I wrong to think that glmmTMB(nbinom1) should result in coefficients that add up to the log treatment means? Quadratic vs linear should only effect the estimate of the variance of the means, yes?

No, it should not and they should not (and there is nothing wrong with glmmTMB). Most GLMs have a fixed mean-variance relationship implied by their link. Gaussian is a very special case where you have two parameters for mean and variance, and you can write the residual variance as an independent term. This isn't true for the negative binomial, hence a different variance function results in different estimates.

Thank you PBulls. But, your response raises the question, why do glm(poisson) and glm(quasipoisson) have same coefficient estimates as glm.nb and glmmTMB(nbinom2) since these also have different mean variance relationships from each other and from the negative binomial.

That only happens in special cases.

The link you provided supports my case -- with a categorical predictor, the coefficients of all models should be the same, and they are except glmmTMB(nbinom1). Note especially the glm(quasipoisson) is the same as both NB fits but not nbinom1. If we add the glmmTMB(nbinom1) fit to the example code in the link you sent, it computes different coefficients (most of the runs). See update to post.
